# Replacing image based on screen size with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to change an image src based on the screen size.

```js
       $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
      if($(window).width() < 568) {
        $("#crewimage").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("resources/images/thecrew.png", "resources/images/thecrewmobile.png"));
        });
      } else if ($(window).width() >= 568) {
        $("#crewimage").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("resources/images/thecrewmobile.png", "resources/images/thecrew.png"));
        });
     }
    });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crew-content">
     <img id="crewimage" src="resources/images/thecrew.png" alt="Header Image"></img>
 </div>
```

My logic seems solid. I'm not sure why its not functional.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: if you have a syntax error why are you posting here?

Comment: I'm saying it might be, I obviously don't know for sure or else I would not be here.

Comment: a syntax error will appear in the console , do you know where the console is?

Comment: It's not a syntax error, I'll edit that part out for you.

Comment: If you want to change image src for a single image, avoid using jquery each. Instead use the id attribute as you are using

Comment: did you just closed a img tag with </img>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jquery's `resize` function.

**Working Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/f0ngoLkq/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="crew-content">
    <img id="crewimage" src="http://completewebgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Mobile-Apps-Development-in-India.jpg" alt="Header Image" />
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(window).resize(function(e){
   if($(window).width() < 568) {
   console.log($(window).width());
    $("#crewimage").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/customers/1633/images/icon_52143.png");
                });
            } else if ($(window).width() >= 568) {
                $("#crewimage").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src","https://ithemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mobile300.png");
                });                        
    }         
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use replace:

```
 <img class="crewimage" src="resources/images/thecrew.png" alt="Header Image"></img>

            $(function() {
            if($(window).width() < 568) {
                $(".crewimage").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src","resources/images/thecrewmobile.png");
                });
            } else if ($(window).width() >= 568) {
                $(".crewimage").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src","resources/images/thecrew.png");
                });
                }
            });
```

note: the images will change only if you refresh the page after the window resize, if you want to change automatically on resize use the `resize event`

second change the ids to classes if you have multiple divs, if you have just one div remove the each loop

Comment: That's much cleaner, I must admit. But unfortunately its still not functioning properly.

Comment: what do you mean properly?

Comment: As in, not working at all. Doesn't replace my image.

Comment: Well now I believe it's trying to do something, but it changes the src to this:<img id="crewimage" src="[object Object]" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Header Image">

Answer (score 0):

Use window resize

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $(function() {
            if($(window).width() < 568) {
                $(".crewimage").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src","resources/images/thecrewmobile.png");
                });
                });
            } else if ($(window).width() >= 568) {
                $(".crewimage").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src","resources/images/thecrew.png");
            });
            });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a valid reason for putting the document ready statement in the resize event?

Comment: Because The resize event triggered automatically. when resize the window. No need to refesh the page.